# Encoding a .json file for a bytecode vm

Tags: python, encode, bytecode-manipulation, vm-implementation

I'm trying to make a Bytecode VM in python just for fun, as a hobby project, but i have a problem, how i can encode a json file like this:

```json
{
 "code": [["0xf2", "Hello"], ["0xf3", 1]],
 "constants": []
}
```

into some file format, something like encrypting, but in some way that it doesn't get so random, i need something more readable but encrypted at the same time.

Comment: Does [minifying](https://codebeautify.org/jsonminifier) your JSON file suit you?

Comment: No, i need to encode/decode it at runtime

Comment: What do you mean by "something more readable"? If you're referring to something human-readable, JSON is your friend. You could try to encode your JSON file to [BSON](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/bson#:~:text=BSON%20stands%20for%20Binary%20Javascript,binary%20formats%2C%20like%20Protocol%20Buffers.).

Comment: That means, for people that doesn't know Portuguese, that BSON worked good!

Comment: Excellent. I will post the BSON suggestion as an answer for you to mark this question as "answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoded files and human-readable files are not always compatible.
However, I believe that [BSON](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/bson#:%7E:text=BSON%20stands%20for%20Binary%20Javascript,binary%20formats%2C%20like%20Protocol%20Buffers.), an encoded JSON variant, is a good solution to your problem.